# SQL Code division not working

Tags: sql

I have divided a Reference number in two parts 'A' and 'B'. and now i have to add columns and add conditions for 'A' line and 'B' line separately.

```
    WIth tab1 AS (
     Select CONCAT(ment.ref_id,'A')  AS ronum,ment.ref_id BillOf from ment 
     where(ment.ata BETWEEN to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')

                                    AND to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'))
     UNION 
 Select CONCAT(ment.ref_id,'B')  AS ronum,ment.ref_id BillOf from ment 
     where(ment.ata BETWEEN to_date('&1','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS')

                                    AND to_date('&2','DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI:SS'))

    select distinct ronum,BillOf from tab1;
```

Now i have to divide the following code for

**Line A AS Amount1 column:**

```
    select sum(charge_amt) 
    from line_charges 
    where ppc_ind='C' 
    and import_export_ind='E' 
    and charge_code='FRTRV' 
    and line_tx_id=ment.line_tx_id
```

**Line A AS Amount2 column:**

```
  select sum(charge_amt) 
    from line_charges 
    where ppc_ind='C' 
    and import_export_ind='E' 
    and charge_code='FSCRV' 
    and line_tx_id=ment.line_tx_id
```

**Line B AS Amount1 column:**

```
   select sum(charge_amt) 
    from line_charges 
    where ppc_ind='C' 
    and import_export_ind='I' 
    and charge_code='HANRV' 
    and line_tx_id=ment.line_tx_id
```

**Line B AS Amount2 column:**

```
     select sum(charge_amt)*0.1
    from line_charges 
    where ppc_ind='C' 
    and import_export_ind='I' 
    and charge_code='HANRV' 
    and line_tx_id=ment.line_tx_id
```

Comment: Please show:  1) your schema; 2) your input data; 3) current results of your queries; 4) desired results of your queries.

Comment: Note that `union` is already distinct, so the `distinct` keyword in the `select` is not necessary.